# Unmarshalling XML attributes with same attribute name in two namespaces

Tags: xml, go

I have an XML structure where I have an unnamespaced "type" attribute, and a namespaced one. I can not get GO's unmarshaller to read both "type" attributes.

The XML is:

```
data := `<response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<map name="bool" type="bool_T" xsi:type="xsd:boolean"></map>
<map name="int" type="int_T" xsi:type="xsd:decimal"></map>
</response>`
```

And my Go/XML definition is:

```
type Typemap struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"map"`
    Name    string   `xml:"name,attr"`
    Type    string   `xml:"urn:debugger_protocol_v1 type,attr"`
    XsiType string   `xml:"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance type,attr"`
}

type Response struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"response"`
    Typemap []Typemap `xml:"map,omitempty"`
}
```

When running the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Typemap struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"map"`
    Name    string   `xml:"name,attr"`
    Type    string   `xml:"urn:debugger_protocol_v1 type,attr"`
    XsiType string   `xml:"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance type,attr"`
}

type Response struct {
    XMLName xml.Name  `xml:"response"`
    Typemap []Typemap `xml:"map,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    rq := new(Response)
    data := `<response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<map name="bool" type="bool_T" xsi:type="xsd:boolean"></map>
<map name="int" type="int_T" xsi:type="xsd:decimal"></map>
</response>`

    reader := strings.NewReader(data)

    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(reader)

    err := decoder.Decode(&rq)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Unmarshalled Content:\n%v", rq)
}
```

The output misses the `bool_T`, and is as follows:

```
&{{urn:debugger_protocol_v1 response} [
    {{urn:debugger_protocol_v1 map} bool  xsd:boolean}
    {{urn:debugger_protocol_v1 map} int  xsd:decimal}
]}
```

If I remove the `urn:debugger_protocol_v1` from the definition, I get the following error:

```
main.Typemap field "Type" with tag "type,attr" conflicts with field "XsiType" with tag "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance type,attr"
```

I can not change the original XML data format. Is there a way to unmarshall both `type` attributes?

I have set up a go [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gB9Qr1TbEcw) too

Comment: I'm not familiar with Go, but I've tried your playground a bit and this certainly seems to be an oversight on the part of the library designers. The actual namespace of those `type` attributes is the null namespace, not `urn:debugger_protocol_v1`, by the way. One idea - you could run the XML through an XSLT that renames the `type` attributes to something else, and then parse the transformed XML. A bit of a roundabout approach, but I reckon it should work.

Comment: It might well be an oversight. I hadn't quite realised it was the null namespace... but I did try using `_` instead of the URN, as that's what the marshalling step showed, but that gave an error, and I don't know how to specify it otherwise. Instead of going the XSLT way, I might just do a string replace if there is no "proper" way of parsing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is currently no way how to do this natively in Go. There is a list of [namespace related issues](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14407), as well as a [specific issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8535) that describes it, but this has not been addressed yet.

However, I also found a workaround. It is possible to write your own unmarshalling code, both for just [attributes](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#UnmarshalerAttr), as well as for [elements](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshaler).

For attributes you can implement something like:

```
type NonMarshalled string

func (s *NonMarshalled) UnmarshalXMLAttr(attr xml.Attr) error {
    fmt.Printf("Parsing attribute '%s', with value '%s'", attr.Name.Local, attr.Value)
    s.Title = strings.ToUpper(attr.Value)
    return nil
}

type Typemap struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"map"`
    Name    string   `xml:"name,attr"`
    Type    NonNamespaced `xml:"type,attr"`
    XsiType string   `xml:"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance type,attr"`
}
```

However, this does not make it possible to have both a namespaced attribute name, and a non-namespaced attribute that has the same name. This will still result in:

```
main.Typemap field "Type" with tag "type,attr" conflicts with field "XsiType" with tag "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance type,attr"
```

The workaround here is to write an unmarshaller for the whole `Typemap` type. In my case, this code looks like:

```
func (s *Typemap) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {                                         
    nameAttr := ""                                                                                                     
    typeAttr := ""                                                                                                     
    xsiTypeAttr := ""                                                                                                  

    for _, attr := range start.Attr {                                                                                  
        if attr.Name.Space == "" && attr.Name.Local == "name" {                                                        
            nameAttr = attr.Value                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                              
        if attr.Name.Space == "" && attr.Name.Local == "type" {                                                        
            typeAttr = attr.Value                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                              
        if attr.Name.Space == "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" && attr.Name.Local == "type" {               
            xsiTypeAttr = attr.Value                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                  

    d.Skip()                                                                                                           
    *s = Typemap{Name: nameAttr, Type: typeAttr, XsiType: xsiTypeAttr}                                                 

    return nil                                                                                                         
}
```